# Three.js Render loop freezing when camera moves

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here is my code: (I am using THREEx,keyboardstate.js for input btw)

```
camera.forward = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1).applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorld).sub(camera.position).normalize();
camera.right = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0).applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorld).sub(camera.position).normalize();

if (keys.pressed('W')) {
    camera.position.add(camera.forward.multiplyScalar(2).multiplyScalar(clock.getDelta())); 
}
if (keys.pressed('S')) {
    camera.position.add(camera.forward.subVectors(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), camera.forward).normalize().multiplyScalar(2).multiplyScalar(clock.getDelta()));  
}
if (keys.pressed('Q')) {
    camera.rotation.y += 0.3 * clock.getDelta();
}
if (keys.pressed('E')) {
    camera.rotation.y -= 0.3 * clock.getDelta();
}

if (light.position.x >= 3) {
    negative = true;
} else if (light.position.x <= -3) {
    negative = false;
}

if (negative) {
    light.position.x -= 0.5 * clock.getDelta();
} else {
    light.position.x += 0.5 * clock.getDelta();
}
```

My issue is, that when I press W, S, Q, or E, the light stops moving? its as if the scene freezes just because the camera is moving / rotating in any way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely it is because the value is being limited to the maximum or minimum range, can you check the ranges being set for the rotation and light position ?

Comment: For the camera, there is no rotation limit. As for the light, the limit all up is 6 on the x axis, if you read the code, it shows this.